# Why conditions from Adapters getView(..) method doesn`t apply correctly to ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView in which I display some products. I use an object that extends the BaseAdapter class to populate the ListView, more exacly using the getView(..) method. I have a TextView "link" on every itemView on which if the user taps it will go to a web page. In my base adapter I set a listener on the TextView only if my product contains a link. 
I have done debugging in my getView(..) method and it all works just fine, but after it exits the getView method, if there is an item that doesn`t have a link it will take the link/listener from another item from the listView.

Adapter Class:

```
public class MatchListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<Match> matchesArrayList;
private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;
private OnClickListener onClickListener;


public MatchListBaseAdapter(Context context, View.OnClickListener listener, ArrayList<Match> results,Activity a) {
    matchesArrayList = results;
    onClickListener = listener;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return matchesArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return matchesArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist_match, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.oferNameMLI2);
        holder.expireDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expireDateMLI);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceMLI);
        holder.companyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.compNameMLI);
        holder.productImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productImageMLI);
        holder.companyImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyImageMLI);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.moreDetailsMLI);
        holder.digitalySigned = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.digitalSignatureImageView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

        //populating the holder.. doesn`t have any relevance..

    if(matchesArrayList.get(position).getCompanyLink() != null){
        holder.companyImage.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        holder.companyImage.setTag(position);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView name;
    TextView expireDate;
    TextView price;
    TextView companyName;
    TextView description;
    ImageView productImage;
    ImageView companyImage;
    ImageView digitalySigned;
}
```

}

Activity onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);

    matches = DataManager.getInstance().getListSubscription().get(DataManager.getInstance().getSubscriptionPosition()).getMatchesList();

    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_layout);
    DataManager.getInstance().setAdapterMatch(new MatchListBaseAdapter(this, this, matches,this));
    lv1.setAdapter(DataManager.getInstance().getAdapterMatch());

}
```

Just want to mention once again that i ve done debugging in the getView(..) method and it was ok, the flow was the right one, but after `the items in the listView that doesn't supposed to have a listener on the TextView it had from the other items.`

`Also this happens always for the first item in the listView .. and it is populated with the link from the last item in the listView that contains a link.`

I've searched a lot for this issue but didn't find anything relevant, but i think that there is a problem on my convertView, but i can`t figure it out..

Thx a lot

Comment: `if(matchesArrayList.get(position).getCompanyLink() != null){...}` ... you sould read about reusing the views in Adapters ... then you will know that you should add `else {....}` code too ...

Comment: Added `else {..}` and stil the same problem...

Comment: what have you add in `else` ... you should put `null` to on click listener and tag of `companyImage`  ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Selvin .. it works ok know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you're reusing the view and not setting an explicit `onClickListener` to it, it still contains the old listener from another product - from the view that was reused.  Try making a change as following:

```
if(matchesArrayList.get(position).getCompanyLink() != null){
    holder.companyImage.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    holder.companyImage.setTag(position);
}
else {
    holder.companyImage.setOnClickListener(null);
}
```

Comment: Yep .. this works perfectly :) thanks a lot! ... The problem was a litle bit more complex because I had this problem not only for the listener above, but also for some pictures where it supposed to show a default picture but it was overrided instead. I also passed null to the asynkTasks that loaded the pictures on else statement and it turned out ok :) ... thanks a lot again !